# Android me/invitable_friends facebook api get short ID

Tags: android, facebook, graph, facebook-invite

I got invitable_friends list, I got data like below

```
{
"id": "AVnRyTe6jbT3TdDNmQQJx1vYFRWt2GPx7zRxNsBiyOOaqVYQhU--1sNQ4gaIy_uDNg8e44-dXTVoSeUakW4lremIeDzLU5O0FRTtoZ7tkZo3cA",
"name": "Marianne Abinguna",
"picture": {
"data": {
"is_silhouette": false,
"url": "..."
}
}
```

But i want get short facebook ID like `100009555113xxx`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can´t get the (App Scoped) User ID with `invitable_friends`. The only way to get User IDs is by using `/me/friends`. Of course you will only get friends who authorized your App too.

It is pointless to get the User IDs anyway, because you are only allowed to use `invitable_friends` to invite friends (to a game with Canvas implementation). You can just use the invite token for that.